# Kohana Validation Rule (This Rule OR That Rule)

Tags: validation, kohana

I am trying to use the Kohana Validation Factory in this way:

```
$post = validation::factory($_POST)     
->rule('payorid', 'not_empty')
->rule('payortype', 'not_empty')

->rule('individual_first_name','not_empty')
->rule('individual_last_name','not_empty')
OR
->rule('orgname','not_empty');
```

On the last three rules, I want it so that EITHER the first two are correct OR the last one is correct.

So if a user supplies a First and Last name it is ok, or if a user just supplies an orgname it is ok.

I can do it with an if statement like this long monster:

```
if((!isset($_POST['individual_first_name'])&&!isset($_POST['individual_last_name']))||(!isset($_POST['orgname'])))
{
exit("A name is empty");
}
```

But I would like to avoid that if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to deal with that:

1. Write your own validation callback. Have a look at the [docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation#adding-rules) for that.
2. Only append the rule you need with something like

```
$post = validation::factory($_POST)     
    ->rule('payorid', 'not_empty')
    ->rule('payortype', 'not_empty');

if ( ! empty($this->request->post('orgname')))
{
    $post->rule('orgname','not_empty');
}
else
{
    $post->rule('individual_first_name','not_empty')
         ->rule('individual_last_name','not_empty');
}
```

I'd recommend the callback, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different version of @Thornsten's approach, validating the first and last name, then validating the orgname. (If, say, you wanted to add other validation rules.)

```php
$org_validate = Validation::factory($_POST)
  ->rule('orgname','not_empty');

$name_validate = Validation::factory($_POST)
  ->rule('individual_first_name','not_empty')
  ->rule('individual_last_name','not_empty');

$post = Validation::factory($_POST)
  ->rule('payorid', 'not_empty')
  ->rule('payortype', 'not_empty');

$errors = array();

if (!$post->check())
{
  $errors = $errors + $post->errors();
}

if (!$name_validate->check() AND !$org_validate->check())
{
  $errors = $errors + $name_validate->errors() + $org_validate->errors();
}
```